# SQL MULTIPLE JOIN-LEFT OUTER JOIN [Find Values between date range]

Tags: sql-server, join, outer-join

I have 4 tables to use JOIN query in MSSQL 
 
1.  **Sales**: ItemID, AreaCode, IndID,Cost 
2.  **Ind**: AreaCode, IndID, Insite,InLocation
3.  **ItemPrice**: ItemID, AreaID, IndID, ActicationDate, Price 
4.  **Invoice**: ItemID, IndID, AreaId, InvoiceDate

I want to get IndID and AreaCode from table 1 on basis of that I want to find records from Ind table and from those records look for Insite and AreaCode with InLocation=’ ’ from same table. 
From that records get IndID .
 Using that IndID and ItemID, find that Price for that particular Item from ItemPrice Table. The price for that particular item is from the activationDate is applicable to specific invoice on basis of date. 
I.e. If Activation Date is 1st Jan and Price is $5 -->And Invoice date is 2nd then Price is $5. But if next day ActivationDate is 2nd Jan and Price is updated to $7. and Invoice is created on 3rd Jan the price should be $7.

I.e.

[image]


Getting this:
[image]

Looking for something like below

 
[image]

```
SELECT DISTINCT sl.AreaCode,sl.IndID,sl.cost,
id.IndID, id.AreaCode, id.InLocation, id.InSite,
id2.IndID, id2.AreaCode, id2.InLocation, id2.InSite,
ip.ItemId,ip.price,ip.ActivationDate,
iv.InvoiceDate 
from Sales s                
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  Ind id 
                ON s.IndID= id.IndID
                AND s.AreaCode=id.AreaCode

    LEFT OUTER JOIN Ind id2 
                ON id.AreaCode=id2.AreaCode
                AND id.IndID=id2.IndID
                AND id.InSite=id2.InSite
                AND id.InLocation = '' 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN ItemPrice ip 
                ON s.ItemId=ip.ItemId 
                AND id2.AreaCode=ip.AreaCode
                AND id2.IndID=ip.IndID  

    LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice iv
                ON s.ItemId=iv.ItemId 
                AND iv.InvoiceDate >= ip.ActivationDate
```

Comment: You say it returns NULL for id2. Do you mean every column from id2 is null? If you want to return only those rows with a match you would need to use an inner join. Perhaps if you created a sql fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) and a clear explanation of what you want as output we can help.

Comment: @Denn: the downvote option is there for a reason. If it was only to be rude, it wouldn't exist.

Comment: I updated the question Its id2.InLocation=' '. Sorry for creating confusion here.

Comment: This is almost certainly a super simple query but without the tables to work with it is just guess work.

Comment: I will try and create SQLfiddle. Thanks.

Comment: so what's wrong with the query you posted?   What results are you getting and how are they different from the results you want?

Comment: Any one ? can suggest ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally cracked.

```
select *, 
   (select top 1 price 
    from itemPrice 
    where itemPrice.ActivationDate <= t.InvoiceDate 
    order by itemPrice.ActivationDate desc) as Price
from Invoice t
```

Here s result 
[image]